# Error: array_map(): Argument #2

Tags: php, categories

Once I've updated WordPress to version 5.3 with this error message:

```
[17-Nov-2019 01:15:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /home/name/public_html/web/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 2069
[17-Nov-2019 01:15:14 UTC] PHP Warning:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/name/public_html/web/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 2069
[17-Nov-2019 01:15:14 UTC] WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND ( 
  wpuw_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (9)
) AND ( 
  wpuw_postm' at line 1 for query SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wpuw_posts.ID FROM wpuw_posts  LEFT JOIN wpuw_term_relationships ON (wpuw_posts.ID = wpuw_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wpuw_postmeta ON ( wpuw_posts.ID = wpuw_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND wpuw_posts.ID NOT IN () AND ( 
  wpuw_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (9)
) AND ( 
  wpuw_postmeta.meta_key = 'ecpt_toparticle'
) AND wpuw_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wpuw_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wpuw_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wpuw_posts.ID ORDER BY wpuw_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5 made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/mydesign/category.php'), WP_Query->__construct, WP_Query->query, WP_Query->get_posts
```

In `category.php` code:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'meta_key'=> 'ecpt_toparticle',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'category__in' => $cat,
    'post__not_in' => $tag
);
$sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();
?>
```

It also doesn't work with the Select tag:

```
<option value="?tag=usa" <?php if ($tag == usa) echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>Usa</option>
```

The only solution I made so far was to revert back to WordPress version 5.2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised answer, based on the code in question and [this](https://www.codepile.net/raw/GQ4ZWVjW.js))*

After the discussion, I realized that:

1. You should replace the `post__not_in` with `tag`; i.e. use `'tag' => $tag`.

   *You should also understand that `post__not_in` should be an **array** of post IDs and not tag/category slugs, names, etc. And if you don't pass an array, then you'd get the error in question, even in WordPress version 5.2.4. :)*
2. You should use `get_query_var( 'tag' )` to get the selected tag (slug).
3. And remove the `category__in`.

So your `WP_Query` code would look like so:

```php
$args = array(                 // then the query args
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // you should use posts_per_page and not showposts
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'tag'            => get_query_var( 'tag' )
);

$sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Additionally:

1. The `select` code (for letting users pick a tag):

   ```php
   <?php $tag = get_query_var( 'tag' ); ?>
   <select name="formal" class="city-choice" onchange="handleSelect(this)"
       data-action="<?php echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'tag', '%tag%' ) ); ?>">
       <option value="">Select a tag</option>
       <option value="usa" <?php selected( $tag, 'usa' ); ?>>Usa</option>
       <option value="italy" <?php selected( $tag, 'italy' ); ?>>Italy</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. The JavaScript code (for submitting the *tag* selected via the above `select`):

   ```html
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function handleSelect(elm) {
       window.location = elm.dataset.action.replace( '%tag%', elm.value );
   }
   </script>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I tested these before too but they do not work in fact posts appear but not where I want.

<option value = "? tag = usa" <? php selected ($ tag, 'usa'); ? >> Usa </option> does not work in ver 5.3

As you see 'post__not_in' => '$ tag' used these items to appear only in the Category and not in the TAG selection.

Example: I have some TAG "USA" when I click on the "USA" tag there I want this meta_key post to stay in Category and not appear in TAG therefore used 'post__not_in' => '$ tag' if any other solution tell me.

Comment: Ok, let me try to understand that. If user chose that option (where `tag` is `usa`), what should happen? What posts should be displayed? What do you mean by "stay in Category"? Can you be more specific?

Comment: And actually, the answer is valid for the error in the question - if you get that error, the reason is because your `post__not_in` value is not an array. Also, `selected()` does work in WP 5.3 - the function simply displays `selected='selected'` if the selected option is the current one in the `<option>`.

Comment: If the user selects TAG "USA" they should display items from TAG and not the item in meta_key:
CODE Meta_key:
<?php
$args = array(
    'meta_key'=> 'ecpt_toparticle',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'category__in' => $cat,
    'post__not_in' => $tag
);
$sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();
?>

Another tag code is down:
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

So all I have in category.php is not using tag.php

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, but can you show the full `<select>` code? Do you use JS to submit the form? Can you show the JS part?

Comment: Hi sure:

<script type="text/javascript">
function handleSelect(elm)
{
window.location = elm.value+"";
}
</script>

<select name="formal" class="city-choice" onchange="javascript:handleSelect(this)">

<option value="?tag=usa" <?php if ($tag == usa) echo 'selected="selected" ';?>>Usa</option>

Comment: What is `$cat` - is it an ID? And from where or how do you get its value? But is this what you want: If user chose a tag, show posts in that tag *and the current category*? Edit: Can you show the full code in your category (`category.php`) template - add it to your question.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know.

Comment: It doesn't work so I want to separate the tag from the pin post.
As for "Select" as a link it works to send the tag but the tag name is removed again in "Select a tag" I want the tag name to stay in that tag.
Example click tag "usa" name should stay on usa not return to "Select a tag"

Comment: This CODE separates from the tag but has the same error as I mentioned above

$tag = get_query_var( 'tag' );
$args = array(
    'meta_key'=> 'ecpt_toparticle',
    'showposts' => 5,
    'cat' => $cat,
    'post__not_in' => $tag
);
$sticky_query = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $sticky_query->have_posts() ) : $sticky_query->the_post();

Comment: Yes, I forgot something with that `select`. Check again the updated answer - or basically, add `<?php $tag = get_query_var( 'tag' ); ?>` before the `<select>`.

Comment: Now it works! I'm sorry for your time! Sinrecerly

Comment: Awesome. :) But I actually *intentionally* removed the meta query (`'meta_key' => 'ecpt_toarticle'`) because earlier on you said, "display items from TAG and not the item in meta_key". If that should actually be included, then just include in it your code. :)

Comment: I add meta_key work fine thanks dear